# Trouble centering UL inside DIV in fluid grid layout

Tags: css

This is something that should be pretty simple, but I've been struggling with this for quite a while now. **I want an unordered list to remain centered inside a div**. The unordered list's **display is set to inline**, and I want to keep a consistent distance between items in the ul.

In my code below you will notice I have '.menu2' set to display:none. For larger windows I have 2 unordered lists structured vertically, sitting side by side. For the smaller windows which I'm working with now I want to hide one of those ul's and the remaining ul I want to be displayed inline. The only problem I'm having is keeping that ul centered with the page.

**Couple of things to note:**

-I'm trying to keep the ul on just one line

-This is just supposed to be for tablet sized windows so because of space the ul needs to take up the whole width of the page.

-When I preview this in a browser and resize the window, I've noticed that it seems like the ul remains a set distance from the left side of my window while as the window size changes the gap on the right side of the ul changes. To try and fix this I have tried giving a % position on the right side, but that didn't make any difference.

```
.menu li   {
list-style-type: none;
width: auto;
font-family: source-sans-pro;
font-style: normal;
font-weight: 200;
float: left;
clear: both;
color: rgba(248,248,248,1.00);
padding-top: 1%;
font-size: 100%;
}

.menu {
width: 20%;
margin-top: 12%;
position: relative;
left: 1%;
float: left;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 482px) {

.menu2 {
display: none; 
 }
.menu {
width: 100%;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.menu li {
display: inline;
clear:none;
padding-left: 3%;
padding-right: 3%;
font-size: 80%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nickatnite_9/8UDC9/embedded/result/

Not exactly how it looks in my page but hopefully it will give you an idea.

Comment: "I wish I could provide a link to show what I'm working on, but since this isn't yet live I'm not sure how I can provide one." -- Use jsfiddle.net to reproduce your issue, using the least amount of code as possible. We can then use the fiddle to help you.

Comment: I can't open your jsfiddle -> (The owner and operator of this website is not the primary producer (per 28 CFR § 75.1c) of any of the visual content displayed on this site.)

Comment: @Nividim Sorry...new to fiddle, try this link. http://jsfiddle.net/nickatnite_9/8UDC9/

Answer (score 0):

It is not working because you have `float: left` at `.menu li`

Remove it and add:

```
display: inline-block;
```